# Why am I not allowed to have repeating IDs in the Primary Key column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, primary-key

I am using MySQL Workbench 6.0 and importing a reasonably large (~55MB) .csv file. The first column consists of reference IDs and the second is dates. The reference IDs read in fine for the first day but when it comes to the second day (when the reference IDs should start to repeat) the information starts to become garbled, though the dates remain correct.

It is also worth noting that I did not have the UN box ticked when I made the table.

I am wondering what is going on here and whether anyone could help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Your title and your question don't seem to have much to do with each other. A primary key has to be unique in any RDBMS.

Comment: Read this one http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

Comment: A PK must be unique. Modify it so that the PK comprises 2 columns that *are* unique, E.g. the ID & Import date

Comment: Please don't linkt w3schools, there's a lot of misinformation there

Comment: Ok. So in order to approach this problem that has information for the same primary key but on different days, would you suggest I split out each day into a separate table?
Basically, I have daily weather information running back over 11 years for 250 different weather stations. This currently all sits in a .csv file that is over a million lines long. I would like to import this into MySQL somehow so I can start to work with it (this is the first time I have used MySQL so I am kind of cutting my teeth on this problem here). What I have done so far is to try and import the whole file.

Comment: Don't use individual tables. Just pick a combination of columns that are unique and make them a composite key. (I.e. a PK that's made from more than one column)

Comment: Or define a separate default-autoincrement primary key that doesn't come from your data at all. When you say that 'the information starts to become garbled' surely you actually mean that the import stops with an error?

Comment: I could do that but the only this is I need to link the data in this huge .csv file with another one that has the references for the IDs, hence they all do need to remain as they are. With regards to it becoming 'garbled', there is information in the columns its just not the same as what is in my .csv file

Comment: Nobody said you can't still use the IDs you have, just not as the primary key. Make it another key.

Comment: Ook. So if I understand you correctly, what I should do is use a separate default-autoincrememnt ID as the primary key and then link the two tables together using the ID that is provided initially.

That is sounding good to me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A primary key is by definition unique. That's basically all: you cannot have a non-unique primary key, so if you have defined it as primary key, you cannot have repeating values.

solutions: make it a non-primary key / index, or add some uniqueness by making it a combined primary key with the date.